# How do I rename an app in MacOS properly?

Tags: applications, macos

I am trying to rename an app in MacOS. I tried it using Finder, navigating to Applications, right clicking on the app to rename, moving to "information" and renaming it there.

This works in most places where the app name appears, but if I have the app opened in fullscreen and I swipe up with 3 fingers I still see the old app name in the menu at the top of the screen.

How can I change the app name also there?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve from this? Apps are essentially 'named at compile' in a .plist inside the app bundle & are not renameable in any real sense by the user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Renaming the .app package in Finder only changes the name there, it doesn't change the name shown in the menu. To do so edit `YOUR.app/Contents/Resources/XY.lproj/InfoPlist.strings` (with `XY` being the language you are using) and change `CFBundleName` there.

For applications without localization files you can also edit `YOUR.app/Contents/Info.plist` and set a new value for `CFBundleName` there.

Comment: This did not work for me. But thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: May also be `CFBundleDisplayName`

Comment: This *should* work for you as it's how we developers set the application name.  Can you share the steps you took so we can see if there's anything missing?

Comment: Tried both of them, but neither works.
To @fsb: I navigated to /Applications/JupyterLab.app/Contents/ and set      <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>Desired Name</string>
same with CFBundleDisplayName

Comment: @Kizame There might be additional entries in that file, so you may need to try them all.

Comment: No, there were no additional entries. But it works when I edit
/Applications/AppName.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj
I think the language specific settings overwrote the general settings I've set before.

Comment: @Kizame Ah, right, the application I tested this with doesn't have any localization. Changing the name in the language-specific files most probably doesn't even have side-effects.

Comment: Will this have any negative consequences for the app doing auto-update or any other issue?