# How can I change the Main Menu name of a copy of TextEdit.app?

Tags: macos, finder, applications, textedit

I am trying to create a duplicate TextEdit.app to be able to have open a very specific set of TextEdit files, not affected by other TextEdit files that may or may not be in use. I can simply copy `TextEdit.app` to `TextEdit copy.app` and it works for most of my needs, The icon in the taskbar says "TextEdit copy", I can use AppleScript to `tell application "TextEdit copy"...` etc. However, that that main menu still says "TextEdit" and I have trouble telling which version I'm in until I open the Windows menu and that's pretty awkward in my workflow.

So I'm looking for solutions to change the Main Menu app name. I found a supposed solution at [How do I rename an app in MacOS properly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/385073/how-do-i-rename-an-app-in-macos-properly). I've found this same "answer" about changing either `CFBundleDisplayName` or `CFBundleName` in either the main `Contents/Info.list' or language-specific` Resources`files such as`Resources/XY.lproj/InfoPlist.strings` in several  places other than this. But for me, this solution does not work.

I'm on Catalina, the latest my hardware supports. When I change the `Contents/Info.list' file and run` TextEdit copy.app`, it crashes. And the` Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings` file doesn't even have "TextEdit" in the file, it's all about Microsoft (weird, yeah?), maybe because of RTF.

You all have TextEdit on your systems. Can anyone give me some guidance on how to change the Main Menu name of a copy of TextEdit?

Comment: If I understand, you want to have one group of files open in one app, and you don't want other text files to open in the same app, for some reason. Could you not just use one of the many other (better) text editors, like BBEdit, for these files (or all others)....? The interface components are compiled, and not easy to modify, and there may be security obstacles in modifying signed software.

Comment: TextEdit has 3 essential features that I have not found in another app: (1) TE supports RTF onts and font sizes. I use that to graphically organize my content. BBEdit doesn't come close. (2) TE has good AppleScript support. AS can create new files or windows as needed, change window sizes, select text, change fonts, etc. I haven't found another RTF (or flexible font using) editor that supports AppleScript as well. (3) TE is very robust when I have to reboot. If Chrome or Xcode hangs and I cannot even switch apps, TE will restore all unsaved editing windows to the same Mission Control Desktops.

Comment: Ah: Ok, if you're using RTF, then ignore BBEdit. But there are plenty of other lightweight word processors like TextEdit that do RTF. Could you use another app for "the other group of files"? It might be useful to know about your overall process, and whether there's another way that you could divide these groups of files within the app; like using different Spaces. I'm intrigued by "organizing content graphically", too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had originally been trying to tweak a Finder copy in the Applications folder of TextEdit.app, a renamed "TextEdit copy.app". I got this advice from Peter Lewis of Keyboard Maestro:

> Mac applications generally cannot be run safely multiple times simultaneously. Both copies will share their preferences (and possibly corrupt each other) unless they are explicitly written for this sort of behaviour (e.g., Chrome I believe). And editing an application will break the code signing, which can cause all sorts of weird behaviours.

That may well be why my following previous suggestions produced apps that crashed.

I'm working on what may be a solution. It's based on the fact that TextEdit is in the public domain, because of the terms under which Apple bought Next. The source code for TextEdit v1.8 build 301 is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/zadr/TextEdit) and the source for v1.9 build 309 is available on Apple's Developer site.

I wrote in the OP:

> I found a supposed solution at How do I rename an app in MacOS properly?. I've found this same "answer" about changing either `CFBundleDisplayName` or `CFBundleName` in either the main `Contents/Info.list` or language-specific Resources files such as `Resources/XY.lproj/InfoPlist.strings` in several places other than this. But for me, this solution does not work.

It turns out that those places, or their equivalents in Xcode, are exactly the places that I need to change the name in the source before I build the app.

Unfortunately, while the GitHub version, 1.8, builds and runs for me under Xcode 11.3 on Catalina, it generates dozens of deprecation warnings and other glitches. But it builds. The v1.9 version has a fatal error when I try to build it.

So I have a path forward that works, for now, and with some effort may last through future OS upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to create a duplicate TextEdit.app to be able to have open a very specific set of TextEdit files...

This is overly complicating things.  You can accomplish what you want with a simple line in Terminal (that can be saved as a script):

```
open -a TextEdit.app foo1.bar foo2.bar ... fooN-1.bar fooN.bar
```

> that that main menu still says "TextEdit" and I have trouble telling which version I'm in until I open the Windows menu and that's pretty awkward in my workflow....So I'm looking for solutions to change the Main Menu app name

If you'd like to get really fancy, you can create a script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 
# Simple bash script to open a set of text files using TextEdit.  
# Filenames are stored in an array named "files_ARR"
# Compatible with Bash 3.2 shipping with macOS

# List of files to be opened
declare -a files_ARR=(/foo/bar/foobar1.txt
  /foo/bar/foobar2.txt
  /foo/bar/foobar3.txt
  /foo/bar/foobar4.txt)


for f in "${files_ARR[@]}"
do
  # Launch TextEdit and open the file
  open -a TextEdit.app ${f}

  # Wait a moment to allow window to properly open.  Value in seconds
  sleep 1
  
  # Rename the Window Title
  osascript -e 'tell application "TextEdit" to set name of front window to "Alternate TextEdit"'
done


exit 0
```

The main benefit behind doing things this way is that you can easily edit the files you need to open as needs dictate *without* having to duplicate (and codesign) the main application.

Comment: Thanks for the problem solving efforts. However, your version is still using the same, single, TextEdit.app. I would get the full list of desired files, but any other files that I open in TE will get merged into the same list, which is what I am trying to avoid. I want this one list of files, that I add to one at a time, to be separate from all other uses of TextEdit, an app unto itself, so to speak. That's why my initial question included changing the name in the Main Menu, because for my specialized purpose, it's *not* TextEdit, per se, it just would have TE functionality.